# Understanding the solution of #14.5.1 in Artin

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory

Here is the question:

Determine a presentation matrix $A$ as an $R-$module for the ideal $ I = (2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ where $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}].$

Here is a solution of the question:

> **Exercise 14.5.1.** Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[\delta]$ where $\delta=\sqrt{-5}$. Determine a presentation matrix as an $R$-module for the ideal $(2,1+\delta).$
>
> *Proof.* Let $\varphi:R^2\longrightarrow I$ that sends $(x,y)\rightsquigarrow2x+(1+\delta)y$. Now
> $$\ker\varphi=\left\{(x,y)\in R^2\,\middle|\,x=-\frac{1+\delta}{2}y\right\}\leftrightarrow\left\{y\in R^2\,\middle|\,\frac{1+\delta}{2}y\in R\right\}$$
> where $\leftrightarrow$ denotes bijection. But $y=2,1-\delta$ are the elements in $R$ with smallest norm satisfying this condition, and moreover the corresponding vectors $(-3,1-\delta),(-1-\delta,2)\in R$ are independent over $R$ since $2r\ne1-\delta$ for any $r\in R$. Thus, $\ker\varphi$ is generated by these two vectors, and by pp. 424-425 we have a presentation matrix
> $$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> -3\phantom{-} & -1-\delta\\
> 1-\delta & \phantom{-}2
> \end{array}\right).\qquad\square$$

**My questions are:**

Here is what I know:

If $I = (2, 1 + \delta )$ where $\delta = \sqrt{-5}.$ Define $\varphi: R^2 \rightarrow I$ by $(r,s) \mapsto 2r + (1+ \delta)s.$ Then $\operatorname{ker}\varphi = 
\left(\begin{matrix}-\frac 1 2(1+\sqrt5i)s\\s\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}-\frac 1 2(1+\sqrt5i)\\1\end{matrix}\right)s.$ And hence a generator for $\operatorname{ker}\varphi$  is $\left(\begin{matrix}-\frac 1 2(1+\sqrt5i)\\1\end{matrix}\right).$ But above in a solution of excercise 14.5.1 in Artin book "Algebra"(second edition) the author did not use this generator when the author needed to use a set of generators of the module of relations to be expressed as a linear combination of the set of generators of $I$ to find a presentation matrix as an $R$− module for the ideal $I$, he did not use that generator.
**1- Does  $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ make any difference in the set of generators I should find?**

**2- Also, why we need the $s$ satisfying the condition of  $\operatorname{ker}\varphi$  to be of minimum norm, could someone clarify this to me please?**

**3-Also, is the solution in the picture above correct?**

Note that this question here [Determining the presentation matrix for a module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1755209/determining-the-presentation-matrix-for-a-module) helped me a lot in understanding the idea of the presentation matrix.

**Note there is no need to answer all questions below as they were already  answered in the comments**

1- why in the second braces $y \in R^2$?

2- How do the author get that that $y =2, 1 - \delta $? And how did we know that they have the smallest norm? and what is the importance of having the smallest the norm in the solution?

3- How did the author get the corresponding vectors $(-3, 1- \delta)$ and $(-1-\delta , 2 )$? how these 2 dimensional vectors belong to $R$? Also, I did not uderstand the argument the author used for showing that they are linearly independent, and why we have to show that they are linearly independent?

4- It seems for me until this point the author is trying to find the coefficients of the set of relations because the columns of the presentation matrix are built from them, is that correct?

5- Finally, is that solution correct?

Could anyone clarify these points to me please?

**Here is also another solution:**

> The surjective map is considered as shown below;
> \begin{align*}
> R^2   & \longrightarrow\varphi(2,1+\delta),\\
> (x,y) & \longrightarrow2x+(1+\delta)y.
> \end{align*}
> As $\ker\varphi$ has two generators. Then, there is the relation that $2(-1-\delta)+(1+\delta)2=0$ and also the relation $2(-3)+(1+\delta)(1-\delta)=0$.
>
> Therefore, two relations cannot be derived from each other. Then $\ker\varphi$ is find by finding $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $2x+(1 +\delta)y=0$.
>
> It means that
> $$\ker\varphi=\left\{y:\ y\in\mathbb{R}\ \text{and}\ \left(\frac{1+\delta}{2}\right)y\ \text{is also in}\ \mathbb{R}\right\}.$$
>
> Therefore, the presentation matrix is
> $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
> -3\phantom{-} & -1-\delta\\
> 1-\delta & \phantom{-}2
> \end{array}\right).$$

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: Please, post only [one question in one post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7132/290189). Posting several questions in the same post is discouraged and such questions may be put on hold, see [meta](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464/290189).

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 I think all my questions related to one question solution ..... this is why I posted them in the same post.

Comment: Ok I will take this into account and I will try as much as I can not to use pictures ..... I just used them here because they are not my solutions. @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會

Comment: oh yeah, but plz type out everything as we have visually impaired users here.  plz be kind to them and don't stop them from viewing your post.  to know more, you may refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/259305.

Comment: Like the hint suggests, consider the kernel of the map $R^2 \to I$ that sends $(r, s) \mapsto 2r + (1 + \sqrt{-5})s.$ Precisely, this kernel consists of all pairs $(r, s)$ in $R^2$ such that $2r + (1 + \sqrt{-5})s = 0.$ From here, it's clear that $(-1 - \sqrt{-5}, 2)$ and $(-3, 1 - \sqrt{-5})$ are both elements of the kernel. (One of these is obvious; the other is a consequence of the fact that $(a - b)(a + b) = a^2 - b^2$ for any elements of a commutative ring.) Check that these are linearly independent in $R.$

Comment: Could you please give me answers to my questions rigorously? @Carlo

Comment: For the second set of braces, it should read $y \in R.$ Check for yourself that this is a bijection. Now, if $y = 2,$ then the fraction in the braces is $1 + \delta \in R$; if $y = 1 - \delta,$ then the fraction is $(1 - \delta)^2/2 = 3 \in R.$ What are the possible norms of elements in $R?$

Comment: Are we using the norm function to show that they are irreducible?@Carlo

Comment: @Carlo by the way they turned out to be not linearly independent. So it seems like the presentation matrix given in the solution is incorrect. Do you have any answers to me?

Comment: @hard, could you elaborate on why you believe they are not linearly independent over R?

Comment: @Carlo 
If two vectors are linearly independent, this means they are not scalar multiples of one another.

$$\begin{split}(-1-\sqrt 5 i, 2)&=c(-3,1-\sqrt 5 i)\\
-1-\sqrt 5 i+3c&=0\text { the first component}\\
c&=\frac 1 3(1+\sqrt 5 i)\\
2&=(1-\sqrt 5 i)c\text { the second component}\\
&=(1-\sqrt 5 i)\frac 1 3(1+\sqrt 5 i)\\
&=\frac 1 3(1+5)=2\end{split}$$

i.e the first vector is $c=\frac 1 3 (1+\sqrt 5 i)$ times the second vector. This means they are linearly *dependent*. This makes sense because both of them are solutions to the system, but the solution space has only dimension 1.

Comment: But is $3$ a unit in $R$?

Comment: @hard, you also mention "dimension," but this is not really well-defined over general rings. I believe that you mean "rank," which is well-defined for nonzero commutative rings.

Comment: @Carlo ok a good catch .... let me check and give you an answer.

Comment: @Carlo ... No the only units of $R$ are $\pm{1}.$

Comment: But why we need them to have the smallest norm? do we need them to be associates?@Carlo

Comment: I know in the ordinary case of linear algebra, a basis element, should not be multiplied by any number. so, sounds like we need the two vectors here to be irreducible ..... is that correct? so we need the vectors in the set of relations to be irreducible? where is this stated in Artin? @Carlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the ring $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is equipped with a norm $\upsilon : R \to \mathbb Z$ defined by $\upsilon(a + b \sqrt{-5}) = a^2 + 5b^2,$ hence $\upsilon(R)$ is a subset of the non-negative integers. Consequently, $$V = \left \{\upsilon(y) \,\, \bigg| \,\, y \in R - \{0\} \text{ and } \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{-5}} 2 y \in R \right\}$$ is well-ordered, i.e., there is a minimum element of $V.$ Considering that the norm of an element $a + b \sqrt{-5}$ of $R$ is of the form $a^2 + 5b^2,$ the possible norms $\upsilon(y)$ are $1, 4, 5, 6,$ etc. But the only elements of norm $1$ are $\pm 1 = \pm 1 + 0 \sqrt{-5},$ and it is straightforward to show that $y$ cannot be $\pm 1$ (by the second condition defining $V$). Likewise, the only elements of norm $5$ are $\pm \sqrt{-5} = 0 + \pm \sqrt{-5},$ and by the same rationale as before, one can show that $y$ cannot be $\pm \sqrt{-5}.$ Clearly, we have that $2$ satisfies both conditions of $V,$ hence $2$ is an element of least norm $\upsilon(2) = 4$ in $V.$ Further, one can show that the only elements of $R$ of norm $4$ are $\pm 2.$ Last, the element $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ with norm $\upsilon(1 - \sqrt{-5}) = 6$ satisfies both conditions of $V.$ Once you know that $\ker \varphi$ is generated by two elements, it suffices to show that $2$ and $1 - \sqrt{-5}$ do not divide each other in $R$ to conclude that $\ker \varphi$ is generated by $(-1 - \sqrt{-5}, 2)$ and $(-3, 1 - \sqrt{-5}).$*

Ultimately, in order to determine a presentation of a finitely generated ideal $I = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ of a ring $R,$ it suffices to find a finite generating set of the kernel of the map $\varphi : R^n \to I$ defined by $\varphi(r_1, \dots, r_n) = r_1 x_1 + \cdots + r_n x_n.$ I don't see how the structure of $R$ changes this goal; however, if your ring $R$ is "nice" (i.e., if $R$ is a field or a Euclidean domain or a principal ideal domain), then this will simplify the problem of finding the generators of $\varphi.$ Unfortunately, the ring $R = \mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ is not even a unique factorization domain, so the argument is a bit tougher.

*Towards this end, observe that every ideal of a Dedekind domain is [either principal or generated by two elements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597543/in-a-dedekind-domain-every-ideal-is-either-principal-or-generated-by-two-element). Once you have shown that $\ker \varphi$ is isomorphic (as an $R$-module) to an ideal of $R,$ it follows that $\ker \varphi$ is generated by two elements (because it contains at least two non-associate elements, as computed in the first paragraph above).

Comment: Why you are excluding the case $y=0$ in your set $V$? is it because its triviality? or what?

Comment: Yes. The zero element is always in the kernel of an $R$-linear map.

Comment: So what shows that the kernel is generated by 2 elements in your argument above?

Comment: what do you mean by the symbol $*$ here $(-3, 1 - \sqrt{-5}).$*?

Comment: Is it just by the last paragraph you stated we know that the kernel is generated by 2 elements?

Comment: @hard, the symbol * is just meant to direct you to the footnote in the last paragraph; it is not a mathematical symbol.

Comment: What about my other question?

Comment: On the matter of why the kernel is generated by two elements, you can show that $\ker \varphi$ is isomorphic (as an $R$-module) to an ideal $J$ of $R$; then, use the linked solution to see that $J$ is generated over $R$ by at most two elements, hence $\ker \varphi$ is generated over $R$ by two elements.

Comment: So all the above is not a proof, it is just a trial for guessing the generators ..... correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed directly as following: let $\phi:R^2 \rightarrow I$ be the surjective map $(x,y)\mapsto 2x+(1+\delta)y$. Compute the kernel

$$ v=(x,y) \in \ker(\phi) \iff x=-\frac{1+\delta}{2}y \ , \ x,y \in R \iff v = (-\frac{1+\delta}{2}y,y) \ , \ y \in R $$

By checking directly $\frac{1+\delta}{2}y \in R$ if and only if you can write $y=(a+2b)+a\delta$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. So you get that the $v \in \ker(\phi)$ can be written as
$$v=(-\frac{1+\delta}{2}(a+2b+a\delta),a+2b+a\delta) = a\cdot(2-\delta,1+\delta) + b\cdot(-1-\delta,2)$$
for $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and conversely. We conclude that a presentation matrix is
$$ \begin{pmatrix}2-\delta & -1-\delta \\
1+\delta & 2\end{pmatrix}$$
Your equivalent presentation matrix is obtained by multiplying the first column by unit $-1$ and then adding the second column to the first one.

Comment: So in general what is the general procedure of finding the presentation matrix?

Comment: I know that the presentation matrix columns are the coefficients of the set of relations?

Comment: but where is the set of relations in our case here?

Comment: **Here is what I know:**

I know from the book "Algebra" by Michael Artin (2nd Edition), on pg.424 (and from my professor lecture), that to find a presentation matrix A, I have to have the following:

$(i)$ a finite set of $n$ generators of $A.$

$(ii)$ a finite set of $m$ generators of $\operatorname{ker}\varphi $ 

Where $\varphi: R^n \rightarrow A$ defined by $e_i \mapsto v_i$ is a surjective $R-$module homomorphism. $A$ is a finitely generated $R$ module and the submodule of relations is $\operatorname{ker}\varphi. $

Comment: where is the set of $n$ generators of $A.$ and where is the  finite set of $m$ generators of $\operatorname{ker}\varphi $ in our case?

Comment: I do not know from where you get this piece of information " $\frac{1+\delta}{2}y \in R$ if and only if you can write $y=(a+2b)+a\delta$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}$. " could you please explain it to me?

Comment: And what is the importance of using the norm function in the solution?